# is it possible to run postgres with no WAL files being produced?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am looking at a way of running a 9.2 postgres database on redhat 6 without any WAL files being produced.

We have a end of day batch process which generates a large number of WAL files (and has filled the disk a couple of times). We also take a pg_dump backup both before the start of the end of day process and also at the end. We are happy that should there be a problem during the batch process to restore the pre pg_dump backup.

When i set the wal_level to minimal we are still getting a large number of WAL files due to the type of database updates which occur. So is it possible to have no WAL files as all (basically a wal_level=none)?

thanks
dave

Comment: There is no way for doing that.  WAL stands for Write Ahead Log, and this is the mechanism how the data and their changes are persisted - the DB cannot live without it.  Read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-intro.html for more details.  You will have to add more disk space and/or rethink the batch job to produce fewer changes.

Comment: Consider using unlogged tables. From CREATE TABLE doc: _Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log_. But you still need to transfer final results to logged tables for durable storage, or to out-of-postgres durable storage if WAL is insufferable.

Comment: @dezso, i was hoping that as i can live with not being able to recover from a crash (as i would restore the backup) there would be a way of not producing them. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Short version: no. PostgreSQL doesn't support generating no WAL whatsoever, because changes to system catalog tables in the `pg_catalog` schema are always logged. There's also transaction ID logging (`pg_clog`), the multixact tracking data (`pg_multixact`), etc, in addition to the xlog, but they tend to be very small.

As Daniel says, you can run with *minimal* WAL generation by:

- Using `wal_level = minimal`
- Creating all tables as `UNLOGGED` or `TEMPORARY` tables

In this case, you will also want to set `fsync = off`, `full_page_writes = off` and `synchronous_commit = off`, since you have no requirement for durability and crash recovery.

Of course, if anything goes wrong (like power loss, unplanned restart, DB server crash, `pg_ctl -m immediate stop`, etc) your data will be totally unrecoverable, but that seems to be what you want.

The rate of WAL creation and rotation with this configuration will be negligible for most applications.

If you don't mind having to re-`initdb` after any restart (even a clean one) you could put `pg_xlog` on a tempfs, but I doubt it's worth the hassle when Pg will generate only a tiny bit of WAL.

You should also check and make sure you don't have WAL archiving (`archive_mode = on`) enabled, that `wal_keep_segments` isn't set. Both of those are only useful if you're doing WAL-based backup or replication. If you don't, then WAL should not accumulate, it should be rapidly recycled. Maybe your checkpoints are set to be much too infrequent, so much so that you run out of disk? Check to see if the `checkpoint_segments` parameter is really really high.

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. The issue isn't stopping PostgreSQL from producing WAL, it's figuring out why it piled up in your batch jobs.

See also: [Optimizing PostgreSQL for fast testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9407442/398670).

Comment: thanks, it's not what i "want" but it would be acceptable :)

to use the UNLOGGED option would be something i would need to speak to the development team about. I'm putting together a few options for the business to discuss and this all helps. Thanks

Comment: What you really want seems to be a non-durable database, by the sounds. It'd *maybe* be possible to make PostgreSQL create catalog tables as unlogged with heavy patching to the code, but I don't think it'd be possible to totally get rid of the xlog. You might want to look at DBMSs that are designed more for this use case, like HSQLDB or H2.

Comment: to be honest the development team have become "wedded" to postgres, and i can't see that changing time soon. The development team are also in control of the database structure (DCL and DDL) so i would probably not be able to convince them to change their code to use UNLOGGED tables. I'm going to test running with MINIMAL logging to see if this reduces the number of WALs. But in the end we will probably end up throwing disk at the problem. cheer.

Comment: If you can't get your dev team to change `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE` then you have a company management problem, not a technical problem. That's absurd, and you're not going to find a technical fix for that problem.

Comment: you could say that, i couldn't possibly comment.

Comment: BTW, WAL shouldn't pile up and fill the disk like that. It's recycled at each checkpoint. So unless you've configured the DB to spread checkpoints out absolutely massively (huge `checkpoint_segments`),  you're using streaming replication with `wal_keep_segments` or you have WAL archiving enabled, it just shouldn't happen. You might want to look into that. It's still worth using `UNLOGGED` tables as it'll greatly reduce writes and thus improve performance considerably, though.

Comment: yes we have WAL archiving enabled. We are shipping to the standby server which is hot standby mode. As the business is "happy" to restore to a backup in the event of failure, i was going to suggest that we stop the hot standby server and therefore we no longer need the WAL archiving (this has been agreed to by the business).  So i then moved on to looking at whether we could remove the WALs entirely.

Comment: Right. Well, if you stop WAL archiving then your running-out-of-space problem will go away anyway as WAL will just get immediately recycled. Note that `UNLOGGED` tables aren't logged to WAL (kind of the point) and therefore cannot be replicated over WAL shipping or streaming replication.

Comment: @davegreen100: if you are concerned about the WAL files, then switch to streaming replication and turn off WAL archiving. Switching all tables to unlogged will effectively exclude them from replication - if that is acceptable you apparently don't need the standby in the first place

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Streaming replication can also result in WAL accumulation if the replica isn't keeping up (in 9.4 with use of a replication slot), or if `hot_standby_feedback` is on and the replica is holding replay for long running queries.

Comment: @CraigRinger, so to turn archive off i am going to set archive_mode=off, archive_command ='', max_wal_senders=0 & wal_level=minimal. Is that everything i need to do? i'm in the process of restoring the production database to test so i can test the no-archival settings. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @davegreen100 Sounds about right. Check your checkpoint settings while you're there; if they're at the defaults they're certainly too low (and you probably get warnings about it in the logs), but also make sure there's enough disk space for `checkpoint_segments * 16MB` WAL segs if it's high. Oh, and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/9407442/398670 if you want to go the non-durable route.